# Setting object to None does not update all references

Tags: python

So i have this piece of code...

```
...
print(F"node id {id(node)}")
print(F"left child id {id(prevNode.get_left_child())}")
node = None
print(F"node id {id(node)}")
print(F"left child id {id(prevNode.get_left_child())}
...
```

This gives me the following output:

```
node id 4860975032
left child id 4860975032
node id 4383750560
left child id 4860975032
```

I would have expected:

```
node id 4860975032
left child id 4860975032
node id 4383750560
left child id 4383750560
```

`prevNode.get_left_child()` Points to the `node` object, but when I set the  `node` object to `None` it does not update `prevNode.get_left_child()` reference. Why is this?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: There is no capital `F` for string formatting

Comment: It works well, you can use both `f` and `F` afaik.

Comment: Mm, I'm doubting myself now. I don't think you can

Comment: @roganjosh You can. Did you try it? `F'{1+1}'` -> `'2'`

Comment: @wjandrea I've only now got chance to test and indeed it works. I'm kinda irked by that but meh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python setting a variable to `None` just means that the variable doesn't point anymore to where it pointed before, other variable names that pointed to the same object, and the object itself remain intact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I would like to set all variables that point to this object to not point to this object. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Well, that's much trickier in Python. You can do some workarounds that would accomplish that, but that's a how Python handles variables.
You can read more [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 1):

You just changed where the variable is pointing to.  You have not touched the objects.

Before:

```
None (4383750560)

objectA <-- prevNode
+-> left_child = objectB (4860975032) <-- node
```

After:

```
None (4383750560) <-- node

objectA <-- prevNode
+-> left_child = objectB (4860975032)
```